# Custom module with possibility to add modules into module to create an expander module in DNN 9.2

Tags: c#, expander, dotnetnuke-9, dotnetnuke

​I'm using **DNN 9.2** and searching for a possibility to create an own module that will work like the [Atlassian Confluence's Expander Macro](https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/expand-macro-223222352.html) where I could add additional content.
In my case I want to add other modules, which will be visible if the parent is expanded and hidden if the parent is collapsed.
I thought about to use a `Pane` control in my module to place several other modules into it. It is an approach that imitates the *Evoq's Grid* module functionality, but with the additional possibility to collapse and expand its content, because of no such (expander) module already exists.

I already tried to achieve it by adding a `Pane` control from `DotNetNuke.UI.Skins` namespace in `Page_Load` method and calling `pane.ProcessPane()`. As I can see in database a added module by moving it into our custom (*expander*) module is related to our pane which is located in our module.
Actually I have some problems by loading and rendering the page, because the module is located under and not in our custom module like it is referenced in database.

Following is my actual code:

**In *.ascx file:**

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="View.ascx.cs" Inherits="Prototype.View" %>

<div ID="TestModuleDiv" runat="server"></div>
```

**In *.ascx.cs (code behind file):**

```
using System;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using DotNetNuke.Entities.Modules;
using DotNetNuke.UI.Skins;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var paneName = "MyTestPane" + ModuleContext.ModuleId;

    var paneControl = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
    paneControl.ID = paneName;

    TestModuleDiv.Controls.Add(paneControl);

    var paneId = paneControl.ClientID.Replace("dnn_", "");

    PortalSettings.ActiveTab.Panes.Add(paneId);

    var pane = new Pane(paneId, paneControl);
    pane.ProcessPane();
}
```

Does somebody have some more information how I could achieve my wanted behavior?

The aim is to create an expander module that could contain several other modules, but we are not sure how we could build it in a best practice way.

**Edit**
Sorry, I missed the fact that I'm searching for an approach with minimized JS magic. Therefore I think it has to happen in code behind.
Furthermore the page must remember which "expander" module was collapsed and which expanded.

Comment: Not sure what are you asking for but what about using Bootstrap collapse?

Comment: Okay, which questions are open that I can clarify them. The aim is to have one module that could contain several other modules. something like a container in a skin that could contain several modules too, but I want it in a module to collapse and expand it.

Comment: Do you previously know the modules you will use or not?

Comment: No, it should be possible to add every in DNN installed module to our custom module.

Comment: How do you plan to add these modules? Also do you know the max number of mudules you could add?

Comment: Via the usual ways, clicking "add module", "add existing module" (reference or copy) or via drag 'n' drop or module's action buttons to move a on page already existing module into our custome module. I would say, the ways you could use to add a module to a page. There should be no limit for the max module amount.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well we have reached an approach that will work like we have expected.

The whole adding/moving modules into the expander module works out of the box and automatically with DNN's own functionality side. We have nothing to implement additionally.

We created an own `Panel` control that inherits from `HtmlContainerControl` and has some logic to use the parent skin as container and furthermore the parent module to get the active Tab (page) from it. This will all happen in method `OnInit`.
Also in `OnInit` method the `OnInitComplete` methods is registered. In this method we are moving all (previously added) modules into the pane. Otherwise the expander module added modules will not be placed inside the expander, but under it.
After that we have to register our own pane control in active tab and have to call finally `ProcessPane` on the pane.

I hope it will help everybody who needs something similar.
I'm very sorry for posting no code, but is an implementation for a customer which I'm not allowed to provide to third persons.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at this open source project:

```
   https://github.com/redtempo/dnnstuff.aggregator
```

The work already has been done.

Comment: Sorry for my late response, but after a very deep dive in, it's not want we expected. It contains several JS logic, we want a solution which works completely without JS. But thank you very much for the approach!