# splitting up ascx files for maintainability

Tags: asp.net, dotnetnuke, skinning

Using DNN (dotnetnuke, dnnsoftware) CMS, does anyone have any idea how to split up skin ascx files (eg. myskin.ascx that uses header.ascx and footer.ascx) but still have the ability to use DNN panes in these header and footer skins?
I'm having some luck but it's not working 100% yet.

A very old post, and a not so old post kind of describes what I'm talking about: https://www.dnnsoftware.com/forums/threadid/302650/scope/posts
[Custom module with possibility to add modules into module to create an expander module in DNN 9.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51408712/custom-module-with-possibility-to-add-modules-into-module-to-create-an-expander)

Basically I'm trying to split the headers and footers from my skins for maintainability. (keeping functionality of panes inside the headers and footers, for example for shopping cart modules)

edit: just registering the control and adding it isn't enough, the child ascx needs to be able to access the DNN panes functionality

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use `<!--#include file="header.inc"-->`